# split Report Builder chart into two chart areas to spread out data

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have a bar chart in Report Builder 2.0 that has a lot of values along the y-axis.  I would like to split the chart to show two chart areas, or even have two separate charts, each with only half of the values on the y-axis.  So chart 1 would have y-axis values A, B, C, and D, while chart 2 would have E, F, G, and H.  I was thinking I could have a filter on the chart so that it only showed rows where ColumnValue < E (for chart 1) and ColumnValue >= E (for chart 2).  How can I write such a filter, though?  It'll probably need to do `Round(Count(ColumnValue) / 2)` to get the index of the middle value, but then how do I actually get what that value is (e.g., E) for comparison?

Or maybe there's some built-in way of prettifying a chart by splitting it into two separate charts to break up a long axis.  I don't know.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try using two graphs from the same source dataset, with a filter on on the first graph like the following:

`RunningValue(Fields!`*GroupFieldName*`.Value,CountDistinct) <= CountDistinct(Fields!`*GroupFieldName*`.Value) / 2`

- and a similar formula on the second, with `<=` replaced by `>` .

Comment: I set this as a filter on the Chart, but cannot save the report due to this error:  "A FilterValue for the chart ‘Chart2’ uses the aggregate function RunningValue.  RunningValue cannot be used in filters."

Comment: I hadn't tried running this in the BIDS report designer - which allows such conditions to be entered and saved as filters against graphs, but returns errors when *running* reports with either aggregate or running total functions! Assuming you are using a SQL data source with windowing analytical functions, such as Oracle or SQLServer, I suggest adding columns to the query to hold the running and grand totals of the distinct count of the number of groups, and then filtering on `Fields!` *RunningTotal* `.Value <= Fields!` *GrandTotal* `.Value) / 2` .